# Does calculating correlation between two dataframes require a loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I have a set of large dataframes that look like A and B:

```
A <- data.frame(A1=c(1,2,3,4,5),B1=c(6,7,8,9,10),C1=c(11,12,13,14,15 ))

  A1 B1 C1
1  1  6 11
2  2  7 12
3  3  8 13
4  4  9 14
5  5 10 15

B <- data.frame(A2=c(6,7,7,10,11),B2=c(2,1,3,8,11),C2=c(1,5,16,7,8))

  A2 B2 C2
1  6  2  1
2  7  1  5
3  7  3 16
4 10  8  7
5 11 11  8
```

I would like to create a vector (C) that denotes the Pearson correlation between A1 & A2, B1 & B2, and C1 & C2. In this case, for example, those correlations are:

```
[1] 0.95 0.92 0.46
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cor` accepts two data.frames:

```
A<-data.frame(A1=c(1,2,3,4,5),B1=c(6,7,8,9,10),C1=c(11,12,13,14,15 ))

B<-data.frame(A2=c(6,7,7,10,11),B2=c(2,1,3,8,11),C2=c(1,5,16,7,8))

cor(A,B)

#           A2        B2       C2
# A1 0.9481224 0.9190183 0.459588
# B1 0.9481224 0.9190183 0.459588
# C1 0.9481224 0.9190183 0.459588

diag(cor(A,B))
#[1] 0.9481224 0.9190183 0.4595880
```

**Edit:**

Here are some benchmarks:

```
Unit: microseconds
                   expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
        diag(cor(A, B)) 230.292 238.4225 243.0115 255.0295  352.955   100
      mapply(cor, A, B) 267.076 281.5120 286.8030 299.5260  375.087   100
 unlist(Map(cor, A, B)) 250.053 259.1045 264.5635 275.9035 1146.140   100
```

**Edit2:**

And some better benchmarks using

```
set.seed(42)
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*n),ncol=n))
B <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*n),ncol=n))
```

[image]

However, I should probably mention that these benchmarks strongly depend on the number of rows.

**Edit3:** Since I was asked for the benchmarking code, here it is.

```
b <- sapply(2^(1:12), function(n) {
    set.seed(42)
    A <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*n),ncol=n))
    B <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*n),ncol=n))

    require(microbenchmark)
    res <- print(microbenchmark(
                   diag(cor(A,B)),
                   mapply(cor, A, B),
                   unlist(Map(cor,A,B)),
                   times=10
                 ),unit="us")
    res$median
})

b <- t(b)

matplot(x=1:12,log10(b),type="l",
        ylab="log10(median [µs])", 
        xlab="log2(n)",col=1:3,lty=1)
legend("topleft", legend=c("diag(cor(A, B))", 
                           "mapply(cor, A, B)",
                           "unlist(Map(cor,A,B))"),lty=1, col=1:3)
```

Comment: + `diag` to get only the values he is interested in.

Comment: Is there a function analogous to `cor` that gives the p-values of the correlation?

Comment: @sds And why is that a problem?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between quadratic and linear algorithms? :-) When you have just 3 columns, it does not matter much, but when the number of columns is in hundreds, this will matter.

Comment: @sds 1. I show exactly that in the answer. 2. It will be extremely rare that you have more than 2^10 columns, which is when this gets bad. I don't understand your downvote.

Comment: How did you produce your benchmarks? (could you please edit your answer to include the code - tia) I find it extremely weird that diag/cor can outperform mapply/cor for *any* input. Can you explain that?

Comment: @sds Mmh? `diag` is extremely fast and doesn't matter much here. If `cor` is passed data.frames, these get coerced to matrices. The matrices are then passed to a C function. And compiled code is much more efficient than `mapply` or `Map`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use friend of apply functions, `Map`, for that.

```
Map(function(x,y) cor(x,y),A,B)
$A1
[1] 0.9481224

$B1
[1] 0.9190183

$C1
[1] 0.459588
```

If you want the output as vector as suggested by @Jilber :

```
unlist(Map(function(x,y) cor(x,y),A,B))
       A1        B1        C1 
0.9481224 0.9190183 0.4595880
```

Or you can just use:

```
 unlist(Map(cor,A,B))
       A1        B1        C1 
0.9481224 0.9190183 0.459588
```

Comment: Since the OP wants a vector, you should use `unlist(·)`.

Comment: +1 for a good example of Map, I still haven't quite wrapped my head around these functional programming concepts in R.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative you can use `mapply` function

```
> mapply(function(x,y) cor(x,y),A,B)
       A1        B1        C1 
0.9481224 0.9190183 0.4595880
```

Or just `mapply(cor, A, B)` as suggested by @Aaron.

Comment: This is what I'd do, though `mapply(cor, A, B)` is sufficient.

Comment: @Aaron how could one apply this thinking to a list of files needing correlations between them? Say A....Z?

Comment: @KennyC: Better I think to start a new question; more detail would be needed.