# calculate correlation on every column

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I want to calculate correlation of V2 with V3, V4, ..., V18:
That is cor(V2,V3, na.rm = TRUE), cor(V2, V4, na.rm =TRUE), etc
What is the most effective way to do this?

```
            V1    V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
1 141_21311223 2.000  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  44_33331123 2.000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3 247_11131211 2.065  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4  33_31122113 2.080  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5 277_21212111 2.090  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks Ananda, you are right, there is no na.rm, I should use 'use="complete.obs"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer, one simple approach would be to use the column positions in a `sapply` statement:

```
sapply(3:ncol(mydf), function(y) cor(mydf[, 2], mydf[, y], ))
```

This should create a vector of the output value. change `sapply` to `lapply` if you prefer a `list` as the output.

I've never seen `na.rm` for `cor` though....

Comment: If the number of column is not really large, it's probably more efficient to use `cor(mydf[,-1])` and subset the result. See my benchmarks [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18535302/1412059).