# R Correlation between successive columns

Tags: r, correlation, sapply

I am trying to write some code to easily calculate the correlation between all successive columns in a matrix.

Let's assume I have columns A, B, C, D, E.

I want the pairwise correlations AB, BC, CD, DE.

In order to avoid writing a loop, I have played around with sapply, but not very successfully, so far.

I'd be grateful for any support.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that `cor` automatically computes all the column wise correlations:

```
cor(df)[cbind(2:ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df) - 1))]
# [1] -0.08727070 -0.10444715  0.06008165  0.18030921
```

Compare to:

```
cor(df$a, df$b)
# [1] -0.0872707 
cor(df$b, df$c)
# [1] -0.1044471
```

Here, we compute the full correlation matrix, and then subset to get the super-diagonal (the diagonal shifted one up from the actual diagonal), which corresponds to the correlations of cols 1 - 2, 2 - 3, etc.  We subset using a matrix, created by `cbind` that specifies all the super diagonal coordinates.

And here is how I generated the data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(5, runif(100), s=F))
names(df) <- letters[1:ncol(df)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to reinvent the wheel. Use the `corrplot` package:

```
require(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, order ="AOE", addCoef.col="gray40")
corrplot(M, order="AOE",method="ellips", col="grey", cl.pos="n",addCoef.col="yellow")
```

to install the package:

```
install.packages("corrplot")
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your quick answers. They look all brilliant. I hat in fact come up with something very close lukeA's solution, but with a mistake. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

Let's reinvent the weel, hehe.

> aaa<-data.frame(a=runif(10),b=runif(10),c=runif(10),d=runif(10),e=runif(10))
>
> diag(cor(aaa[,1:(dim(aaa)[2]-1)], aaa[,2:(dim(aaa)[2])]))

Comment: `diag(cor(aaa[,-ncol(aaa)], aaa[,-1]))` is a bit more succinct.

Comment: This solution is calculating a lot of correlation values that aren't required. This is fine if the problem is small, but not very efficient since you are only interested in the diagonal values.

Comment: @Marcinthebox See [these benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535231/correlation-loop-function-in-r/18535302#18535302).

Comment: @Roland - Not sure how you got your benchmarks exactly, but I think your wrong if you're implying that diag(cor()) is fast. See my quick and dirty benchmark added to my answer. The `mapply`version supplied from your link, as well as my function and lukeA's perform the best. Cheers, Marc

Comment: @Marcinthebox The benchmarks depend on number of columns and number of rows. If you set `n <- 50` calculating the whole correlation matrix ist faster. If you have only 100 rows its even faster if n==1000.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `sapply`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a=runif(100), b=runif(100), c=runif(100), d=runif(100))
sapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), function(x) cor(df[x], df[x+1]))
# [1] 0.017032146 0.009675918 0.103959503
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops aren't always bad - especially if you know how big your results vector should be in advance, then fill it in.

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(50), nrow=10, ncol=5)
succ.cor <- function(x){
    n <- ncol(x)
    col1 <- seq(n)[-n]
    col2 <- seq(n)[-1]
    res <- seq(col1)
    for(i in seq(res)){
        res[i] <- cor(x[,col1[i]], x[,col2[i]])
    }
    res
}

succ.cor(mat)
#[1] -0.37670337  0.60402733  0.08296412  0.34192416
```

Here is a better comparison of speed between some of the methods presented here:

```
set.seed(1)
m=3000
n=1000

A <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(m*n), m, n))

#lukeA
t1 <- Sys.time()
tmp1 <- sapply(1:(ncol(A)-1), function(x) cor(A[x], A[x+1]))
lukeA.diff <- Sys.time() - t1
lukeA.diff

#Rufo
t1 <- Sys.time()
tmp2 <- diag(cor(A[,1:(dim(A)[2]-1)], A[,2:(dim(A)[2])]))
Rufo.diff <- Sys.time() - t1
Rufo.diff

#Marc in the box
t1 <- Sys.time()
tmp3 <- succ.cor(A)
Marcinthebox.diff <- Sys.time() - t1
Marcinthebox.diff

#BrodieG
t1 <- Sys.time()
tmp4 <- cor(A)[cbind(2:ncol(A), 1:(ncol(A) - 1))]
BrodieG.diff <- Sys.time() - t1
BrodieG.diff

#Jilber (from  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18535544/1199289)
t1 <- Sys.time()
tmp5 <- mapply(cor, A[,1:(dim(A)[2]-1)], A[,2:(dim(A)[2])])
Jilber.diff <- Sys.time() - t1
Jilber.diff
```

#### Results of performance:

```
t(data.frame(Jilber.diff,  Marcinthebox.diff, lukeA.diff, BrodieG.diff, Rufo.diff))
Jilber.diff       "0.2349489 secs"
Marcinthebox.diff "0.2255359 secs"
lukeA.diff        "0.408231 secs" 
BrodieG.diff      "6.042533 secs" 
Rufo.diff         "12.20104 secs"
```

So it seems like `mapply` approach is also fast. lukeA's and mine as well..