# In R, how can you calculate P-values using cor() when you have multiple variables?

Tags: r

I've got a large data set (120 data points and 10+ variables) that I want to explore using a correlation matrix:

```
H5<- log[ which(log$Harvest=="e"), ]
H5.cor <- cor(H5[sapply(H5, is.numeric)])
```

I presented the data using the package [corrplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html):

```
corrplot(H5.cor, method = "number")
```

Additionally to this would like to know the P - value of each of the correlations. I know that I can use `cor.test()` but as I understand it, it needs an X and a Y value.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, you can check `rcorr` from `library(Hmisc)`

Comment: Thanks man, just playing now with putting it into corrplot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535231/correlation-loop-function-in-r/18535450#18535450