# Do I need to loop through vector elements in R to calculate correlation?

Tags: r, vectorization

I have created two vectors and "cleaned" the data.  I am looking to loop through each element in each vector as pairs, in order to calculate the correlation of each pair and store in a third vector.

I am able to see each element and print - however, the cor() function is producing a result of NA.

Code is below, any advice is appreciated.

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)

  dat <- data.frame()
  cleandat <- data.frame()
  correlation <- c()

  for (count in 1:length(files_list)) {
    dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[count]))
    cleandat <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
  }

  if (nrow(cleandat) <= threshold) {
    print("Nope.")
  } else {
    sulfate_data <- cleandat$sulfate
    nitrate_data <- cleandat$nitrate

    for (element in 1:length(sulfate_data)) {
      print("Sulfate: ")
      print(sulfate_data[element])
      print("Nitrate: ")
      print(nitrate_data[element])
      print(cor(sulfate_data[element], y = nitrate_data[element]))
      correlation <- cor(sulfate_data[element], y = nitrate_data[element])

    }
  }
  print(correlation)
} #end corr()
```

Comment: You are getting `NA` because you are trying to correlate a single value with another single value - which does not make sense. Perhaps you just want `cor(sulfate_data, nitrate_data)`, if they are the same length?

Comment: `cor()` is already vectorized. Simply do `cor(sulfate_data, nitrate_data)`! If there may be some NAs, use `cor(..., na.rm=T)`

Comment: Thank you!  Your replies provided me with clarity, I think I had misunderstood the problem but now know what to do. Much appreciated!

Comment: FYI, R even vectorizes the calculation of [correlation between **two dataframes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535231/does-calculating-correlation-between-two-dataframes-require-a-loop)!